# When is a series of matrices divergent. How to define divergence in this case?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series, divergent-series, infinite-matrices

In Quantum Mechanics we deal with series of operators represented as matrices like

$$e^A = 1+ A + \frac{A^2}{2} + \dots$$

and similarly for $\sin(A) $, etc., where $A$ is a matrix. Now my question is

> How to define convergence and divergence of a series of matrices?

Like with real numbers if $u_n $ is the $n$-th term of the series then if it does not tend to $0$ we can definitely say that the series is divergent.

For matrices is it just that the $n$-th term should tend to the $\mathbf{0}$ matrix or something else. Because a series of real numbers is divergent if the sum tends to $\pm \infty$ or doesn't tend to anything.

What about a series of matrices. When is a series of matrices divergent. Are there telescopic or alternating series too. What are the tests to verify convergence.

---

**Edit:** I didn't still understand how do we test the convergence for the series of matrices. Are there any standard tests. Can anybody let me know which is one is used to test the convergence of $\exp(A)$, $\sin(A)$, i.e., the one test which is frequently used. Or at least a test to test straight forward divergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of $d\times d$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is typically equipped with the topology such that:

- A sequence of matrices $ A^{(n)} = [a_{ij}^{(n)}]_{1 \leq i,j \leq d}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ if and only if each $ a_{ij}^{(n)}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ for each pair of $i, j$.

So you may apply any of the famous convergence tests to each of the entry. Alternatively, this topology is realized by any of the matrix norm $\| \cdot \|$ such as the Frobenius norm

$$ \| A \|_{F} := \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{d} |a_{ij}|^2} $$

or the operator norm

$$ \|A \| := \sup_{v : \|v\| = 1} \| Av \|. $$

Then many of the convergence test for the series of real/complex numbers continues to apply if the role of absolute value is replaced by any of the matrix norm:

- If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| A_n \| < \infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ converges.
- If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|A_n\|^{1/n} < 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ converges.
- If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|A_{n+1}\|}{\|A_n\|} < 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ converges.

---

However, many of the operators appearing in quantum mechanics are unbounded operators on infinite-dimensional spaces, which necessitates knowledge on the field of functional analysis.

Comment: Ok I understood. Just one thing. What problem unbounded operators cause to the above criterias..

Comment: @Shashaank, That an operator $A$ is unbounded literally means that its operator norm $\|A\|$ is infinite. So the topology arising from the operator norm cannot deal with such an operator. That is where functional analysis kicks in. For instance, certain unbounded operators (such as selfadjoint operators, also known as Hermitian operators in quantum mechanics literature) admits the famous Spectral Theorem and thus the functional calculus $f(A)$ may be developed for a wide range of functions $f$.

Comment: thank you I got it now.... Could you pls suggest an "easy' text in functional analysis too... I am good at linear algebra at the level of Hoffman kunz..

Answer (score 0):

> Convergence of a series of matrices means convergence of all entries.

It is standard to consider holomorphic functions of matrices $f(A)$.

> But if your interest is quantum mechanics, you usually need to consider unbounded operators and of course we need a different approach in that case.

Comment: Is there a straight forward test for divergence like in the case of real number series. And do the same tests for convergence like Cauchy test etc carry on to each entry of the matrix or not

Comment: Sure, all is essentially the same in case we speak of the entries. For other questions, please ask them separately.